# Why "Segmentation fault(core dumped)"?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Ok, so, I know a segmentation fault occurs when a program attempts to access a memory location that it is not allowed to access. So, I checked my code to see if that's the issue but it seems to me that it is able to access all the required memory locations, then why the error?

This is what I have done :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "aes.h"
#include <string.h>
#define CCHMAXPATH 100

void encrypt(const char *fileIn, const char *fileOut, const unsigned char *key);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  unsigned char key[100];
  char buffer[CCHMAXPATH];
  int i;
  srand(time(NULL));

  for (i=0; i<argc; i++)
    printf("%d:  %s\n", i, argv[i]);

  aes_init();
  snprintf(key,100,"/home/ankita/bin/python/project/encrypt/%s.encrypted", argv[1]);
  encrypt(argv[1], key, argv[2]);

  return 0;
 }

 void encrypt(const char *fileIn, const char *fileOut,const unsigned char *key)
 {
   int i;
   aes_encrypt_ctx ctx[1];
   unsigned char iv[16]; /* initialisation vector */
   unsigned char inBuffer[200], outBuffer[200];
   FILE *inFile = fopen(fileIn,"rb");
   FILE *outFile = fopen(fileOut, "wb");

   /* pick a random initialisation vector */
   for(i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
      iv[i] = rand() & 0xFF;
   fwrite(iv, 1, 16, outFile);

   aes_encrypt_key256(key, ctx);
   while((i = fread(inBuffer, 1, sizeof(inBuffer), inFile)) > 0) 
   {
     aes_ofb_crypt(inBuffer, outBuffer, i, iv, ctx);
     fwrite(outBuffer, 1, i, outFile);
   }
   aes_ofb_crypt(inBuffer, outBuffer, i, iv, ctx);
   fwrite(outBuffer, 1, i, outFile);

   fclose(inFile);
   fclose(outFile);
   }
```

Now this is what happens at the commandline :

```
$./amaze /home/ubuntu/Documents/txt/2mb.txt abc
0:  ./amaze
1:  /home/ubuntu/Documents/txt/2mb.txt
2:  abc
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So, like I said, I checked using the **'for'** loop and as expected, **argv[1]** is the filepath along with filename, **argv[2]** is the key. Then what is wrong? Which part of memory is inaccessible? Why am I still getting "Segmentation fault(core dumped)"?

Comment: You've posted your `main` function, but the problem is likely to be in your `aes_init` or `encrypt` functions.  Have you used a debugger to find the line where the crash actually occurs?

Comment: Turn on core dumps and load core file in debugger(there you can dig for segfault reasons)

Comment: You might want to print the output filename, after the `snprintf` line. And you might want to rename the variable called `key` since it's not being used as the key, but is being used as a filename.

Comment: `/home/ankita/bin/python/project/encrypt//home/ubuntu/Documents/txt/2mb.txt.encrypted` can't open file. You used the file pointer is NULL probably.

Comment: @Wyzard - I've just now updated my post so you can see the rest of the code as well.
When I try debugging, it says - 
""/home/ubuntu/Documents/txt/2mb.txt" is not a core dump: File format not recognized"

Comment: You're debugging it wrongly. There's plenty of gdb tutorials around, it's handy to learn how to debug, so go do that. Also, check that your 2 fopen() calls succeeds.

Comment: Always check return values of system functions. In particular, your crash here may possibly be because some `fopen` returns `NULL`. Another possiblitity would be `fread` returning -1, and then `aes_ofb_crypt` handling it as unsigned value. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're getting argument names confused.  You're putting the output file name in a variable named `key`, and passing `key` in as the `fileOut` parameter of `encrypt()`, and passing `argv[2]` in as the `key` parameter.  This sort of confusion doesn't break things, but it should be fixed.

Also you're stickinjg the whole absolute path "/home/ubuntu/Documents/txt/2mb.txt" with the `snprintf` call resulting in `key` containing `"/home/ankita/bin/python/project/encrypt//home/ubuntu/Documents/txt/2mb.txt.encrypted"` which is almost certainly not what you intended.  It might be that your `fopen(fileOut, "rb")` call is failing and returning `NULL` but you're not checking it.

You're using `key` with `aes_encrypt_key256` which presumably requires 256 bits of key material, but you're passing in `argv[2]` which is only guaranteed valid ro 4 bytes (`"abc\0"`).  The function is trying to pull 32 bytes out of the key parameter.